# Python Tkinter Opencv refresh caneram after long time will be slowly

Tags: opencv, tkinter, python-3.5

**Version**

- Python 3.5.2
- opencv 4.0.0-alpha

**Question**

The execution of the program is very smooth at first,but after about 5 minutes,the fps will drop drastically.According to the execution time of each code line,it seems to be deleayed in the update image.

Please Help me fix this bug

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
import time
import cv2
import threading
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
speed = ""
def clear():
    global exit
    while True:
        success, photo = camera.read()
        cv2.waitKey(250)
        if(exit):
            break
window = Tk()
imageFrame = Frame(window, width=600, height=500)
imageFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)
lmain = Label(imageFrame)
lmain.grid(row=0, column=0)
start = 0
while True:
    lmain.configure(image='')
    lmain.image = ''
    speed = ""
    start = time.time()
    success ,photo = camera.read()
    speed = speed + (str)((int)((time.time()-start)*1000))
    speed = speed + "ms   "
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(photo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    speed = speed + (str)((int)((time.time()-start)*1000))
    speed = speed + "ms   "
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    speed = speed + (str)((int)((time.time()-start)*1000))
    speed = speed + "ms   "
    imgtk = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    speed = speed + (str)((int)((time.time()-start)*1000))
    speed = speed + "ms   "
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.image = imgtk
    speed = speed + (str)((int)((time.time()-start)*1000))
    speed = speed + "ms   "
    window.update()
    speed = speed + (str)((int)((time.time()-start)*1000))
    speed = speed + "ms   "
    print("Result: " + (str)(speed))
    fps = (int)((1000/(time.time()-start))/1000)
    print("FPS: " + str(fps))
```

Comment: I keep around 30 FPS after running for 10 minutes in my notebook (Python 3.7.2 in Windows 7).  BTW, you don't need to clear the image at the beginning of while loop.

Comment: @acw1668 After 10 minutes the fps still keep at 30FPS?PS. i running it on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yes, still keep around 30 FPS after 10 minutes.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank for your reply.I have already try another way to make GUI.The FPS is much higher and more stable.